# How secure is window.location for identifying the hosted server

Tags: javascript, security, code-injection

I have a script that will be inserted into an unknown number of other websites via a <script> tag. After being inserted, the script will read the window.location of the webpage and use that information to bring in content that is specific to that webpage.

How secure is window.location when attempting to determine the host name of the webpage loading the script? Is it easily spoofed?

Comment: It's secure as the browser is.

Comment: The test in your script is easily modified or bypassed so it's all kind of irrelevant if you're trying to defend against people messing with things.  No client-side javascript code is safe from tampering.

Comment: What do you mean by "easily modified or bypassed"? Doesn't any attempt to change `window.location.href` result in a page redirect?

Comment: ANYTHING from javascript is extremely easily spoofed. in fact, anything from any client is easily spoofed. be careful, youre headed for quick disaster if you really need security for whatever youre doing here.